# Cannot type PIN number into chakra pin using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm having trouble testing  Chakra stack pin inputs. This is the HTML, part of the Chakra UI library.

```html
<div id="pin-stack" class="chakra-stack css-8vjnke">
  <input aria-label="Please enter your pin code" inputmode="numeric" type="tel" id="pin-input-:r1:-0" 
    autocomplete="one-time-code" placeholder="○" class="chakra-pin-input css-jyb0wy" value="" data-index="0">
  <input aria-label="Please enter your pin code" inputmode="numeric" type="tel" id="pin-input-:r1:-1"
    autocomplete="one-time-code" placeholder="○" class="chakra-pin-input css-jyb0wy" value="" data-index="1">
  <input aria-label="Please enter your pin code" inputmode="numeric" type="tel" id="pin-input-:r1:-2"
    autocomplete="one-time-code" placeholder="○" class="chakra-pin-input css-jyb0wy" value="" data-index="2"> 
  <input aria-label="Please enter your pin code" inputmode="numeric" type="tel" id="pin-input-:r1:-3"
    autocomplete="one-time-code" placeholder="○" class="chakra-pin-input css-jyb0wy" value="" data-index="3">
</div>
```

This is the test

```js
cy.get('#pin-input-:r1:-0').type('1234')
```

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` string has `:` characters in it, but this character is also used in other selectors for example `:has()`.

The result of this is the `id` is being cut off at the `:` character.

Effectively it is using `cy.get('#pin-input-')` instead of `cy.get('#pin-input-:r1:-0')`.

The other way to query with an id is to use a **full attribute**, putting the whole `id` string in quotes so that the selector does not get split up.

```js
cy.get('[id="pin-input-:r1:-0"]').type('1234')
```